# iPhone: Access to number of missed calls and number of unread messages?

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

I'm wondering whether there is a way to get the number of missed calls, and the number of unread messages, on an iPhone (which is not jailbroken).

I basically would like to know what the current batch icon of the Phone app and the Messages app are displaying. There is no need to get the details of individual calls or messages.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NO there is no way`.

Unfortunately currently it is not possible with current SDK. If you want to get details regarding current calls you can certainly do that with current SDK.

Here are links of resources from APPLE for [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) and [SampleApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) using which you can get further idea about tracking current call information.

Comment: Hi @Jennis did u find the solution to access call history in iOS5.x. Please reply

Comment: @AppleVijay Still they have not made API public for the same. You can check for jailbroken devices though.

Comment: It is a shame. I wanted to write an application reporting annoying phone numbers (there are such apps for Android).